# RavenDB Alternative to Polling (push notifications)

Tags: ravendb

I have an app that uses RavenDB. It has a WPF front-end GUI app. I would like for that app to be notified of certain types of new documents. For example, if my app loads the most recent 50 Foos for display, and someone else adds 10 more Foos later, I would like the app to know about these new 10 and update the UI.

I could poll the DB every few seconds to check for new documents, but it would be nice to have a real-time, two-way call-back notification from RavenDB. Does this functionality exist?

My searches have ended with smuggler and listeners, but I don't know that either is intended for this purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[RavenDB V2 will support push notifications](http://ayende.com/blog/160129/what-is-up-with-ravendb-2-0):

```cs
store.Changes()
    .ForDocument("users/1")
    .Subscribe(notification => {
        using(var session = store.OpenSession())
        {
            var user = session.Load<User>(notification.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Wow! " + notification.Name + " changed. New name: " + user.Name);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, Thomas. Is the v2 release date known yet?

Comment: No date's been published yet, as far as I know. I guess it's done when it's done :)